# Llamando dos funciones PHP en un archivo HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo cierta información en una base de datos en `MySql`. Quiero mostrar esta información en una página `HTML` apoyándome de `PHP`.

Cuando muestro la información de sólo una tabla no hay problema. El problema viene cuando quiero mostrar otra tabla en la misma página. El código es el siguiente:

**functions.php**

```
<?php
require "config.php"; /*Archivo de conexión a BD*/

class eventosEscolares{
function __construct($db){
    $this->db= $db;
}

public function informacionA(){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM info_a");
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
public function informacionB(){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM info_b");
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

}
?>
```

**desplegar.php**

```
<?php
require_once "functions.php";
$db = new DatabaseConnection();
$evento = new eventosEscolares($db->pdo);

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="main-nav">
<div class="container">
<a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
<a href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
<a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
<a href="#">Anuncios</a>
</div>
</nav>


<div id="p_div">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Día</td><td>Descripción</td>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
$inf=$evento->informacionA();
foreach($inf as $evento){
    $i++
?>
<tr><td><?php echo "$evento[dia]" ?></td><td><?php echo "$evento[descripcion]" ?></td></tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>


<table>
<tr>
<td>Día</td><td>Descripción</td>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
$infb=$evento->informacionB();
foreach($infb as $evento){
    $i++ ?>
<tr><td><?php echo "$evento[dia]" ?></td><td><?php echo "$evento[descripcion]" ?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Haciéndolo de esta manera obtengo el error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function informacioB() on array in
>   desplegar.php on line 59

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo para que me muestre ambas tablas correctamente?

Comment: No se si lo copiaste mal aqui, o lo tienes mal en tu codigo, pero el error esta diciendo que no hay tal cosa como una funcion informacioB(). Puedes notar que le hace falta la "n" antes de abrir parentesis. Es posible que tengas un error tipografico?

Comment: dice error en la linea 59. Mas alla de todo lo que te estan marcando, estaria bueno en la pregunta remarcar cual es la linea 59

Answer (score 0):

el error es de sintaxis:

```
Call to a member function informacioB()
```

Esta funcion no existe, revisa si esta bien escrito

ADEMAS:

los arrays estan mal deberian ser: `$evento['dia']` usando comillas simples en vez de `$evento[dia]` y asegurate que sean igual a los nombres de las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a:

- Primero creas la variable **`$evento`** haciendo `$evento = new eventosEscolares($db->pdo);`, lo que devuelve un `object`.
- Mas adelante llamas a `$inf=$evento->informacionA();`
- **Aquí el error**: Al iterar la variable `$inf`, haciendo `foreach($inf as $evento)`, lo que sucede es que la variable `$evento` ahora es una `array` y no un `object` (*instancia de `eventosEscolares`*).

### Solución:

Podrías usar otro nombre para la variable donde asignas los valores del arreglo `$inf`, es decir, en lugar de `$evento`, podrías usar `$data`

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
require_once "functions.php";
$db = new DatabaseConnection();
$evento = new eventosEscolares($db->pdo);

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="main-nav">
<div class="container">
<a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
<a href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
<a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
<a href="#">Anuncios</a>
</div>
</nav>


<div id="p_div">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Día</td><td>Descripción</td>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
$inf=$evento->informacionA();
foreach($inf as $data){
    $i++
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $data['dia'] ?></td><td><?php echo $data['descripcion'] ?></td></tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>


<table>
<tr>
<td>Día</td><td>Descripción</td>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
$infb=$evento->informacionB();
foreach($infb as $data){
    $i++ ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $data['dia'] ?></td><td><?php echo $data['descripcion'] ?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```